# How to create a public facing website?

Tags: sharepoint-online, public-website

I recently came across a post that said Microsoft is discontinuing the external public facing website on SharePoint and we'll have to use some third party app.
I have to create a a public facing website for a client on SharePoint itself,what should i  use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct that Microsoft have removed the SharePoint public sites. Instead they suggest to get a public website from a third part provider.

Right now they suggest either [GoDaddy](https://in.godaddy.com/) or [WiX](https://www.wix.com/my-account/sites/dc61185e-690a-4cda-927c-b6064af9aa1e) from the Office 365 admin center.

The official announcement from Microsoft states the following:

> As part of the evolution of the Office 365 service, we periodically
>   evaluate the capabilities of the service to make sure that we’re
>   delivering the utmost value to customers. After careful consideration,
>   we concluded that for public websites, Office 365 customers would be
>   better served by third-party providers whose core competency is public
>   websites. Therefore, we’ve made the difficult decision to discontinue
>   the SharePoint Online Public Website feature so that we can focus our
>   efforts and investments on delivering capabilities in Office 365 that
>   will bring more value to our customers.

[Information about changes to the SharePoint Online Public Website feature in Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3027254/sharepoint-online-public-websites-to-be-discontinued)

Comment: so there actually no way to do that on sharepoint? what i  think i need  to do is create a web app on azure and host my website?

Comment: Good question but I unfortunate can't answer. I guess that the 2 providers have some special site for **office 365** subscriptions but i'm not sure how it will work with several SharePoint services.

Comment: Yes, you could use an Azure Web App, but not SharePoint. If you MUST use SharePoint you have to install and license it separately and use a Publishing Site template. The licenses for Public/Anonymous access is totally different from the Office 365 or CAL based license model.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you use on-prem you could still use it for a public site. I don't know about the licensing. There used to be a special license for an internet facing farm