# Is there a way to make public facing SPO Communication site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, anonymous-authentication, public-website, anonymous-access

I know that SPO Public sites are not supported anymore. But I need to find a way to make a SharePoint Online Communication site public i.e I want to enable anonymous access to the site **without having the users to sign in to Microsoft Accounts**.

Is this possible or I just have to go to a third-party vendor? I really want to use SharePoint for a public facing site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not supported to share the full site anonymously. We can only share documents and folders with everyone that don’t require sign-in in SharePoint Online.

By default, external sharing is disabled in communication sites, you can enable it in new SharePoint admin center->active sites->select communication site->click “sharing” in the ribbon->select “Anyone”.

Share SharePoint files or folders for your reference:

[Share SharePoint files or folders](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fShare-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_Toc371328496).

Similar issue post:

[Is there a way to make public facing SPO Communication site?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/414bf0fc-3c1f-4beb-bcb5-7b0bd75c92ef/is-there-a-way-to-make-public-facing-spo-communication-site?forum=sharepointadmin)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding and as you already know [SharePoint Online Public Websites are discontinued](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/sites/public-websites-be-discontinued) by Microsoft, currently there is **no way of using public site in SharePoint Online**.

Instead Microsoft is suggesting to **get a public website from a third party provider**.

**Why is Microsoft making this change?**

> As part of the evolution of the Office 365 service, we periodically evaluate the capabilities of the service to make sure that we’re delivering the utmost value to customers. After careful consideration, we concluded that for public websites, Office 365 customers would be better served by third-party providers whose core competency is public websites. Therefore, we’ve made the difficult decision to discontinue the SharePoint Online Public Website feature so that we can focus our efforts and investments on delivering capabilities in Office 365 that will bring more value to our customers.

**Similar Questions**:

1. [How to create a public facing website?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227497/how-to-create-a-public-facing-website)